# How to use keydown event inside <i> instead of button

Tags: html, angular, angular12

```
<button class="fa fa-caret-down font-size-18px" style="border: none"
  #pop="bs-popover"
  [popover]="fil"
  placement="bottom right"
  [adaptivePosition]="true"
  [outsideClick]="true"
  (keydown)="keydownEvent($event,pop)">
</button>
```

In my angular application, I am using a button which will open a popover. But I want it to be a  tag or something other than a button because the button will be activated when we press space or enter keys which I don't want. The code should be like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-caret-down font-size-18px" style="border: none"
  #pop="bs-popover"
  [popover]="fil"
  placement="bottom right"
  [adaptivePosition]="true"
  [outsideClick]="true"
  (keydown)="keydownEvent($event,pop)">
</i>
```

But this will not trigger the keydown event. What might be the reason for it what are the alternatives? Thanks

Comment: If it is a button, use a `button` Why wouldn't you want it activated by space bar? If you want to use a different element than a button you have to make it focusable first. `tabindex="0"`

Comment: @cloned because initially, it was <i> tag only not a button. I was just trying it with a button to see if keydown event works. it's a little down arrow dropdown that opens a popover. The button is also fine but then I will have to add additional CSS classes to remove borders. Dropdown shouldn't work on pressing enter and space keys should they?

Comment: Of course they should work on enter and space key, do you never navigate a website by using keyboard? The CSS to remove borders from a button is quite simple: `border: 0` ... Then maybe set a background-color and you are done. There is no excuse for not using a button, you can style it with ease to look how you like to.

Comment: Does it have to be `keydown` listener? A `click` listener would work, outcome would be the same imo. `(click)="keydownEvent($event,pop)"`

Comment: @cloned Well, that's true. My job was to upgrade code from angularJs to angular12 so I was just replicating the code. That's a fair point and I will consider this, thanks.

Comment: @Joosep.P click is a mouse event and i don't think pressing keyboard key will trigger it.

Comment: Yeah, `(click)` won't work for keyboard keydown (now I see why you want the keydown). I didn't realize that the requirement is that popup should be triggered by keyboard. But like @cloned pointed out it would be good to convert it to an invisible button and have `fa-caret-down` on the button.